# Mockito: define mock behaviour

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to test a class, which depends on external service. This external service amends objects, passed to it:

```
public void methodF(Op op) {

    ...

    // op.operationId == 0

    externalService.registerOp(op);

    // op.operationId == 123456L

    if (op.getOperationId() == 0) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }

}
```

If I mock external service it doesn't amend op and whole method, which is being tested, fails with exception.

How do I define mock behaviour to fake amending an operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [write an Answer](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2014/03/whenhow-to-use-mockito-answer.html) to provide an arbitrary implementation for a mock method.

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>()) {
  @Override public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    Op argument = (Op) invocation.getArguments()[0];

    // Your code here
    argument.operationId = 123456;

    return null;
  }
}).when(externalService).registerOp(any(Op.class));
```

For non-void methods, you can also use [thenAnswer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) instead of [doAnswer](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)).

If you find yourself writing the same answer over and over, or mocking many operations on the same class, consider writing an alternative implementation (e.g. FakeExternalService or UnitTestExternalService) that stubs this operation directly, which will likely be more readable and more type-safe.

Comment: +1 Or make `Op` an interface type and mock the return call that gives the ID value.

Comment: @Duncan Not a bad idea, but it looks like Op might be a data object, and mocking data objects can be laborious and futile. ExternalService here is a direct collaborator and would need to be mocked in any case.